# PHPUnit doesn't generate xml log

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have PHPUnit 3.6 and I have configured my phpunit.xml to generate a xml log but it doesn't generate xml log. The coverage report is generated correctly. I am doing anything wrong?

```
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/coverage" title="Name of Project"
  charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"
  lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="./log/clover.xml"/>
    <log type="junit" target="./log/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
</logging>
```

Comment: This works for me on 3.6.9. How are you running your tests? Command-line? IDE?

Comment: Ohh It works from command line. I guess the problem may be in netbeans...What could be wrong to netbeans?

Comment: @DavidHarkness Maybe add this as the answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you point NetBeans to your project's `bootstrap.php` and `phpunit.xml` files.

1. Right-click the project in the **Projects** tab.
2. Select **Properties**.
3. Select **PHPUnit** in the list on the left.
4. Check **Use Bootstrap** and type or browse to `bootstrap.php`.
5. Check **Use XML Configuration** and type or browse to `phpunit.xml`.